# Remove digits outside alphanumeric characters using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
details = "| 4655748765321 | _jeffybion5                    | John Dutch                                                    |"
```

The end product I want is this:

```
>>> details
>>> _jeffybion5 John Dutch
```

My current code removes all digits including those attached to strings, also ignores the whitespace between two or more strings.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> details = "| 47574802757 | _jeffybion5                    | John Dutch                                                    |"
>>> details = re.sub("[0-9]", "", details)
>>> details = re.sub(" +", "", details)
>>> details = details.replace("|", " ") 
>>> details
>>> _jeffybion JohnDutch
```

Any help to achieving the desired result would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you can do this without regex

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just do `" ".join(x.strip() for x in details.split("|")[2:])` or something along the lines?

Answer (score 3):

#### Non-Regex Solution

One approach:

```
chunks =  details.split()
res = " ".join(chunk for chunk in chunks if not chunk.isnumeric() and (chunk != "|"))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
_jeffybion5 John Dutch
```

#### Regex Solution

An alternative using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
res = " ".join(re.findall(r"\w*[a-zA-z]\w*", details))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
_jeffybion5 John Dutch
```

A third alternative using also `re.findall`:

```
res = " ".join(re.findall(r"\w*[^\W\d]\w*", details))
```

The pattern:

```
[^\W\d]
```

matches any word character that is not a digit.

The regex solutions are based on the idea that you want *strings* composed of letters and numbers (also underscore) with at least one letter (or underscore).

Comment: works +1 but it was ask using regex :/

Comment: @ArrowRise See the update

Answer (score 2):

With your shown exact samples please try following regex.

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+([^|]*)
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/o22Q9l/1) for above regex.

***Python3 code***: Using Python3x's `re` module's `split` function to get required output.

```
import re
##Creating x variable here...
x="""
| 4655748765321 | _jeffybion5                    | John Dutch                                                    |
"""
##Getting required output from split function and data manipulation here. 
[x.strip(' |\||\n') for x in re.split(r'^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+([^|]*)',var) if x ][0:-1]

##Output:
['_jeffybion5', 'John Dutch']
```

***Explanation:*** Using regex `^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+([^|]*)` to get required output, this is creating 2 capturing groups which will help us to fetch values later. Then removing new lines or pipes from `strip` command further. Then removing last item of list, which is empty one created by split function.

Answer (score 2):

For the example data, you might remove a pipe surrounded with optional whitespace chars, and optionally remove digits followed by whitespace chars till the next pipe.

Then strip the surrounding spaces.

```
\s*\|\s*(?:\d+\s*\|)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7TzJN0/1)

```
details = "| 4655748765321 | _jeffybion5                    | John Dutch                                                    |"
res = re.sub(r"\s*\|\s*(?:\d+\s*\|)?", " ", details).strip()
print(res)
```

Output

```
_jeffybion5 John Dutch
```

---

If there should be a char A-Za-z in the string, you could split in `|` between whitespace chars and check for it:

```
details = "| 4655748765321 | _jeffybion5                    | John Dutch                                                    |  | "
res = " ".join([m for m in re.split(r"\s*\|\s*", details) if re.search(r"[A-Za-z]", m)])
print(res)
```

Output

```
_jeffybion5 John Dutch
```